# An `awk` method to print after the last `/` on every line of a text file

Tags: awk

I'm in need of an `awk` method to print after the last `/` on every line of a text file. I've got a txt file which includes file directories.

~/2500andMore.txt file

```
/Volumes/MCU/_ 0 _ Mt Cabins Ut/Raw/Log Cabin on The Stream/DJI_0003.JPG
/Volumes/MCU/_ 0 _ Mt Cabins Ut/Raw/DJI_0022.jpg
/Volumes/MCU/_ 0 _ Mt Cabins Ut/PTMAD/Insta/RAW/IMG_1049.jpg
```

The idea is to copy files that are all on one directory back to the example given. I'm planning to do something like this to copy them back:

```
awk '{print <after the last '/' of the line>}' ~/2500andMore.txt > ~/filename.txt

cd file-directory

while IFS= read -r file && IFS= read -r all <&3; do cp $file $all; done <~/filename.txt 3<~/2500andMore.txt
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your example, you don't need to put the filenames into a separate file, just change your while loop:

```
while IFS= read -r all; do
    file=${all##*/}            # Or file=$(basename "$all")
    cp "$file" "$all"
done <~/2500andMore.txt
```

But if you really want the filenames in `filename.txt`, then use:

```
awk -F / '{ print $NF }' ~/2500andMore.txt > ~/filename.txt
```

Explanation: "/" is used as a separator and `$NF` represents the last field

Comment: > file=${all##*/}

That did the trick. Shell paremeters. Thank you.